# Why we get error "Unable to mock class * due to missing dependency"?

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins, mocking, jmockit

Why we get error "Unable to mock class * due to missing dependency" in test case when a maven project runs on Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is resolved when I updated JMockit version from 1.7 to 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs if JMockit, when attempting to mock a class, gets a `NoClassDefFoundError` from the JVM. This will usually indicate that the class to be mocked depends on some other class which was not found in the runtime classpath during class loading, probably due to a missing jar file. The full stack trace should include the reason for the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Thanks @Rogério. This error is resolved when I updated JMockit version from 1.7 to 1.11.